# What is best practice to install Package in ubi-minimal which is not in offical repo but in CentOS

Tags: docker, package, centos, yum, ubi

I am trying to make small container which uses `qeum-img`, `qemu-kvm`.

How can I install package **which is not in offical ubi-minimal repository but in CentOS 8 Appstream?**
* I know that both ubi-minimal and CentOS 8 Stream are almost same because it is originated from Fedora.

### My Environment

Local OS: CentOS 8 Stream
VM (Container) OS: ubi-minimal

### About package and repository

```bash
[root@computer1 ~]# cat /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Stream-AppStream.repo
# CentOS-Stream-AppStream.repo
#
# The mirrorlist system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick current mirrors that are geographically
# close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates unless you are
# manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist does not work for you, you can try the commented out
# baseurl line instead.

[appstream]
name=CentOS Stream $releasever - AppStream
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$stream&arch=$basearch&repo=AppStream&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/$contentdir/$stream/AppStream/$basearch/os/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

[root@computer1 ~]# dnf list | grep qemu
ipxe-roms-qemu.noarch                                             20181214-11.git133f4c47.el8                                @AppStream
libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu.x86_64                                 8.0.0-14.module_el8.8.0+1257+0c3374ae                      @appstream
qemu-guest-agent.x86_64                                           15:6.2.0-28.module_el8.8.0+1257+0c3374ae                   @appstream
qemu-img.x86_64                                                   15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm.x86_64                                                   15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm-block-curl.x86_64                                        15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm-block-gluster.x86_64                                     15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm-block-iscsi.x86_64                                       15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm-block-rbd.x86_64                                         15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm-block-ssh.x86_64                                         15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm-common.x86_64                                            15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm-core.x86_64                                              15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm-docs.x86_64                                              15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm-hw-usbredir.x86_64                                       15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm-ui-opengl.x86_64                                         15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
qemu-kvm-ui-spice.x86_64                                          15:6.2.0-34.module_el8+407+df018485                        @appstream
```

As you can see, we can find `qemu-img` package in appstream repository.

However, in ubi-minimal, there is no `qemu-img`

```bash
[root@d3c0cf37860b /]# microdnf repolist *qemu*

(microdnf:133): librhsm-WARNING **: 10:10:14.681: Found 0 entitlement certificates

(microdnf:133): librhsm-WARNING **: 10:10:14.681: Found 0 entitlement certificates
error: Unknown argument *qemu*
```

### What I tried to solve this problem

1. 

There is [source code for building myself](https://www.qemu.org/download/) but, it needs `make`. In order to do this, there should be `gcc` `make` etc. which removes the benefit of using minimal version of container base image.

2.

I tried to find all dependencies for using qemu-img in [rpmfind](https://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=qemu-img). However, there are too many dependencies and also, it looks not cool. I think there is more ARTISTIC way to solve this problem.

3.

I already read below two articles but it won't help.

- [Chapter 7. Adding software to a UBI container](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/building_running_and_managing_containers/assembly_adding-software-to-a-ubi-container_building-running-and-managing-containers)
- [Migrating your base Image from CentOS to UBI](https://connect.redhat.com/en/blog/migrating-your-base-image-from-centos-to-ubi)

The funny thing is the package, that they used for example, `bzip2` and `httpd` can easily find in original repository like below command.

```bash
[root@d3c0cf37860b /]# microdnf repoquery *bzip*

(microdnf:136): librhsm-WARNING **: 10:18:21.931: Found 0 entitlement certificates

(microdnf:136): librhsm-WARNING **: 10:18:21.932: Found 0 entitlement certificates
bzip2-1.0.8-8.el9.x86_64
bzip2-devel-1.0.8-8.el9.i686
bzip2-devel-1.0.8-8.el9.x86_64
bzip2-libs-1.0.8-8.el9.i686
bzip2-libs-1.0.8-8.el9.x86_64
libzip-1.7.3-7.el9.i686
libzip-1.7.3-7.el9.x86_64
```

What I want to know is "**If there is no package in official repository of ubi, how to handle it?**"

Comment: did you find a way?

Comment: @user2700022 Some of them are in EPEL. So, I added EPEL Repository with rpm. Some of them, which are not exist, get rpm from CentOS and copy at `docker build`.